# bucle while para correccion de errores

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una especie de menu para una calculadora en java, con un switch doy a elegir entre 3 valores (1, 2 y 3) y dentro del case 1, hago otro switch para elegir los submenus (a, b, c y d), mi problema es que necesito que si introduces un valor que no es valido (Un valor distinto de a, b, c o d) vuelva a pedirme un valor valido por teclado, en el primero menu lo he conseguido con un if (Si no el valor no es 1 o 2 o 3) y un do-while (Mientras el valor sea distinto de 1, 2 o 3 pide de nuevo un valor por teclado) Pero en el submenu no consigo hacer que funcione de la misma forma. Adjunto una captura. Gracias por adelantado. https://imgur.com/a/HgI8a

```
            System.out.println("a. Suma");           
            System.out.println("b. Resta");           
            System.out.println("c. Producto");           
            System.out.println("d. División");

            opcion = keyboard.nextLine();   
            char b = opcion.charAt(0); 

            if ( b != 'a' || b != 'b' || b != 'c' || b != 'd' )

                do {

                    System.out.println("Introduce un valor valido");
                    opcion = keyboard.nextLine();   
                    b = opcion.charAt(0);
                } while ( b != 'a' || b != 'b' || b != 'c' || b != 'd' );

            switch (b) {

                case 'a':
```

Quiero que si introduzco por teclado la letra a, b, c o d no entre dentro del if y del bucle if, con este codigo escriba lo que escriba por teclado el programa entra dentro del bucle y no sale nunca. Solo quiero que se entre dentro del if y del bucle si se escribe cualquier otra cosa que no sea a, b, c y d.

Comment: Deberías evitar agregar imágenes porque no pueden ser indexadas en Google. Te invito a editar tu pregunta y adjuntar el código :)

Comment: perdon no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta.. podrias explicar que es lo que quieres exactamente

Comment: Ya he agregado mas informacion de lo que quiero exactamente

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar todos los || (OR) por && (AND).

Básicamente, quieres que si el usuario no introduce ninguna de las letras permitidas, le muestres el mensaje de error y hacerle escribir otra vez.

La condición que necesitas es: Si la variable b no es igual a "a", y además, no es igual a "b", y además, no es igual a "c", y además, no es igual a "d"... Es decir, que se cumpla que la variable no tiene ninguno de esos 4 valores.

Usando OR estás diciendo que si la variable no tiene alguno de esos valores, error. Por tanto cuando el usuario escriba "a", aunque es una opción correcta de tu menú, entrará en el if porque se cumple que "a" no es "b", ni "c", ni "d". Es como tratar de pedirle al usuario que introduzca una letra que sea "a", "b", "c" y "d" al mismo tiempo, no sé si me explico.

Con AND obligas a que entre en el if si se cumplen TODAS las condiciones del if.

Con OR haces que entre en el if si sólo una de las condiciones del if se cumple.

Quedaría así:

```
        if (b != 'a' && b != 'b' && b != 'c' && b != 'd')

        do {

            System.out.println("Introduce un valor valido");
            opcion = keyboard.nextLine();
            b = opcion.charAt(0);
        } while (b != 'a' && b != 'b' && b != 'c' && b != 'd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de solucionar el problema puede ser usar el `default` en el `case` statement asi dependiendo del valor de `b` puedes correr el codigo en el case o si es cualquier otro se vaya al `default`. Sin embargo en este caso tendrias que poner el case dentro de un `while` y crear una variable `boolean` para salir de dicho `while`.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, sería excelente si agregaras un poco de código como ejemplo :), saludos.